# How can I get Google account recovery to recognize an email address with periods?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

Okay so I have two Gmail accounts: one is for business and one is for personal use. Let's just say my business account is jane.doe@gmail.com, and my personal is johnsmith@gmail.com. These are all old accounts back when Google still recognised period and capitalisation as important elements of email address.

I use my business email as the backup account for my personal one and vice versa.

So basically I got locked out of my personal account because I forgot the password. I still can access my business account however. The problem starts when I use Google's recovery method. The system requires me to input the email address for my recovery account (my business account). But the thing is because Google now ignores period and capitalisation, it sees my answer as incorrect. Instead of analysing my answer as jane.doe@gmail.com, it only reads it as janedoe@gmail.com. So is there a way to make Google Account Recovery recognise the period in my email address?

I know that my business account is the recovery account for my personal email. Google even gave me the clue (the first three letters of my backup account). I have asked around on Google Forum but to no avail, they don't give me definite answers. Honestly there is a whole loophole in this Google mechanism that I'm surprised Google isn't aware of this.

Comment: I made a slight modification to the title that I think will make this more visible in the search engines.  Feel free to tweak the wording as necessary.

Comment: Okay thank you! I barely got some sleep last night, and I just typed in what I thought made sense in my head.

Comment: No worries.  Your existing title made complete sense to me, but I figured this would be a better representation.